# Deleting a remote branch not reflecting on the origin

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using my two laptops and my personal GitHub account to simulate two developers working in a team using git. My repo only has a `master` and a `feature` branch, and a simple text file.

On one laptop (one developer's account) I use the command line bash to issue git commands. I merge feature with master and then delete it locally: `$ git branch -d feature`

Of course, pushing alone is not going to delete the remote feature branch, so I do: `$ git push origin --delete feature`

I, then, expected to see this remote deletion to show on the other laptop (the other developer uses **SourceTree** to do git stuff) but the origin feature on SourceTree is still there, despite several refreshing...

I looked around, thinking that perhaps there are other commands for this. I came across the following two:

```
$ git push origin :feature

$ git push -u origin feature
```

However, I get the following two errors for each of the above git bash commands (the first developer):

```
error: unable to delete 'feature': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyRepo/Repo.git'

error: src refspec feature does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyRepo/Repo.git'
```

These two error messages show that the remote feature branch has indeed been deleted. **Right**?

What am I missing? Why does the remote branch deletion done by the first guy does not take effect on the remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanup remote deleted branch (and else) in local:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

See the remote branch list(s):

```
$ git branch -r
```